# How to configure Apollo cache for specific GraphQL queries?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo-client, directus

1. I am using [Directus CMS](https://github.com/directus/directus) (version: RC-50) + Next.js + Apollo Client + React Hooks
2. All GraphQL queries for custom data in Directus are fetched inside `items`

```
query getCategories {
  items {
    category {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

```
query getArticles {
  items {
    article {
      id
      title
    }
  }
}
```

3. I have a problem with Apollo Cache: it's not working and all queries are being refetched every time when component's rerenders.
4. I read [the article](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/#typepolicy-fields) of how to set type policies for Apollo, but can't understand, how to apply it for my schema: I don't have any IDs inside the `items` field...
5. Getting an errors from Apollo:

[image: Apollo error 1]

[image: Apollo error 2]

6. Does anyone have any solutions for similar problems?

Comment: why not to ask directus maintainers about this [insane] design decision?

Comment: This question is more about Apollo configuration, that is not connected with Directus. I like Directus and I hope this can be properly configured :)

Comment: I hope Directus can be configured to be Apollo (most popular graphql client) compliant, like milions of other APIs ... why do you think it is only Apollo problem? They decided, probably they have a solution? Or they don't know it is a problem, maybe they should?

Comment: I don’t think there is any problem in Apollo, I just think, that I can’t properly configure it. Anyway I’ll contact Directus devs also.

Comment: This question is not valid anymore due to Directus has divided queries now:

https://github.com/directus/directus/releases/tag/v9.0.0-rc.54